# In AWS Codepipeline how do you skip a database cluster deploy step

Tags: aws-codepipeline

I have an AWS Aurora database cluster that will need to be deployed to multiple environments. I'd like to make this easier on our Ops team by just including this cluster deploy in the the code pipeline but I need to add a conditional to prevent the database cluster from being deployed on successive builds and I'm not sure how to do this. I believe I should use a precondition on this build step but how do I check if the cluster has already been deployed?

Comment: What do you mean by: prevent the database cluster from being deployed on successive builds

Comment: When building my database cluster I noticed that if I already had the clustered and tried to manually deploy it again the deploy would fail. I did not realize the codepipeline step would not run if no changes had been made so I didn't want my deploy to fail if the database had already been deployed.

Comment: Can you make the action succeed if there are no updates to perform? This is, for example, how the CloudFormation action works.

Comment: I guess I'm not being clear enough. There's no need to do anything. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like codepipeline will not run a step if the information about it has not changed so Amazon handles this issue.

Comment: CodePipeline runs every action for a given pipeline execution. Perhaps you mean to say that pipeline executions are triggered by a change?